# How to calculate a Lotus Notes Footer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I want to add a footer to a Lotus Notes document. The Lotus Notes form "Printing" tab allows me to add a footer. However I would like to calculate the footer based on the value of a field on the form rather than just adding text. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't show field content in print footer.

The only thing possible is inserting document's window title with `&W`.
Form's `Window Title` formula can be calculated with field contents.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use this as a solution.